# How scrapy write in log while running spider?

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapyd, portia

While running scrapy spider, I am seeing that the log message has "DEBUG:" which has 
1. DEBUG: Crawled (200) (GET http://www.example.com) (referer: None)
2. DEBUG: Scraped from (200 http://www.example.com)

I want to know that 
    1. what to those "Crawled" and "Scraped from" meant for?
    2. From where those above both ULRs returned from(i.e. while scraping page which variable/argument has holding those URLs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me try to explain based on the `Scrapy Sample Code` shown on the [Scrapy Website](http://scrapy.org). I saved this in a file `scrapy_example.py`.

```
from scrapy import Spider, Item, Field

class Post(Item):
    title = Field()

class BlogSpider(Spider):
    name, start_urls = 'blogspider', ['http://blog.scrapinghub.com']

    def parse(self, response):
        return [Post(title=e.extract()) for e in response.css("h2 a::text")]
```

Executing this with the command `scrapy runspider scrapy_example.py` it will produce the following output:

```
(...)
DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://blog.scrapinghub.com> (referer: None) ['partial']
DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://blog.scrapinghub.com>
    {'title': u'Using git to manage vacations in a large distributed\xa0team'}
DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://blog.scrapinghub.com>
    {'title': u'Gender Inequality Across Programming\xa0Languages'}
(...)
```

`Crawled` means: scrapy has downloaded that webpage.

`Scraped` means: scrapy has extracted some data from that webpage.

The `URL` is given in the script as `start_urls` parameter.

Your output must have been generated by running a spider. Search the file where that spider is defined and you should be able to spot the place where the url is defined.